# Are $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I know $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^2$ are not homeomorphic.but

> Are $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$ homeomorphic?

Comment: From Wikipedia: $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are not homeomorphic for $m ≠ n$.  I'm not sure why though

Answer (score 7):

$\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbb{R^m}$ aren't homeomorphic for $m \neq n$. An easy proof using algebraic topology can be given: remove a point from each of the two spaces. Then the spaces become homotopic to $S^n$ and $S^m$ respectively. But $nth$ homology group of $S^m$ is $0$ if $m \neq n$. So, $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbb{R^m}$ aren't homeomorphic for $m \neq n$.

Comment: OP's special case can be done with (slightly) less advanced machinery by instead considering the fundamental group; but the idea is the same.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Yes.. but I like the homology approach better :)

Comment: @MikeMiller how does it work with the fundamental group in this case?

Comment: @IttayWeiss: Removing a point, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not simply connected, but $\mathbb{R}^3$ is. That statement can be translated in terms if $\pi_1$

Comment: @voldemort ah yes, OP only wanted dimensions 2 vs. 3.